# NSDocumentDirectory remove folder

Tags: ios, swift, nsdocumentdirectory

I have created a folder inside documents directory using :

```
fileManager.createDirectory(atPath:ziPFolderPath,withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
```

In this folder I have placed few files.
Later in the app, I want to delete not just the files inside the above folder, but also the folder.
`FileManager` supports `removeItem` function but I am wondering if it removes the folder as well.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Yes it will delete folder also.**

**From the documentation of:**  - [`removeItem(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filemanager/1413590-removeitem)

> Removes the file or directory at the specified URL.

**From the documentation of:**  - [`removeItem(atPath:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filemanager/1408573-removeitem)

> Removes the file or directory at the specified path.

**Edit:** You can call it like this way.

```
try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: URL(fileURLWithPath: ziPFolderPath))
//OR
try? FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: ziPFolderPath)
```

Comment: Ok. But what will be the path or Url I'll pass. Because the document root directory has that folder as well as sqlite file. I want just the folder to be deleted.

Comment: @Nitish You need to pass the path of that zip directory. Also Check the edited answer

Comment: That does the purpose

Comment: @Nitish Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5**

Also you should check if file exist at path or not and check for error also.

```
do {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    // Check if file exists
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: urlfilePath) {
        // Delete file
        try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: urlfilePath)
    } else {
        print("File does not exist")
    }
} catch {
    print("An error took place: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)removeItemAtPath:(NSString *)path 
                   error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error;
```

path is the string indicating directory or folder to remove. Its a NSFileManager method.

you can also check here https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilemanager/1408573-removeitematpath?language=objc

Comment: PO is asking for a solution written in Swift.